# Importing Google Play Services into Eclipse hangs

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services

I just found I needed this for the map service. Thus I upgraded to newest SDK / Google Play Services.

I then in import it into Eclipse... But when I click "Finish nothing happens?

[image: nothing happens on import when clicking finish]

Anything looks wrong in above screenshot? I am pretty sure I have followed instructions, but I must be missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If u want to use the google-play-services u have to add the lib to ur project.

```
1. Create ur own android project
2. Project right click -> Properties
3. under java build -> library u can add the lib of google-play-services .
4. use services
```

Answer (score 1):

Flag "copy project into workspace". And maybe you need to set your project to use this Google project as a library.

Answer (score 1):

select path like this

> /extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib

and note this point.

> To develop using the Google Play services APIs, you must download the
>   Google Play            services SDK

.may be there is no lib project is in your folder ,check that.

> http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, I had downloaded it. Not sure why it did not work. But used Benjamins methods instead.

Answer (score 1):

**Be Careful, Follow these steps and save your time**

1. Right Click on your Project Explorer.
2. Select New-> Project -> Android Application Project from Existing Code
3. Browse upto this path only - "C:\Users**your path**\Local\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\google_play_services"
4. **Be careful browse only upto - google_play_services and not upto google_play_services_lib**
5. And this way you are able to import the google play service lib.

Let me know if you have any queries regarding the same.

Thanks